# Как тестировать BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

Есть broadcast receiver отвечающий за включение/выключение блютуза.Как для него написать тест ?И какие можно для него написать тесты 
Вот и сам receiver

```
public class BluetoothAdapterStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    interface ChangeState{
        void enableAdapter();
        void disableAdapter();
    }

    private static ChangeState mChangeState;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // When discovery finds a device

        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch(state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    mChangeState.disableAdapter();
                    Log.e("Core2", "STATE_OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Log.e("Core2", "STATE_TURNING_OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    mChangeState.enableAdapter();
                    Log.e("Core2", "STATE_ON");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Log.e("Core2", "STATE_TURNING_ON");
                    break;

                 case BluetoothAdapter.ERROR:
                     break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }


    public  void registerCallback(ChangeState changeState){
        mChangeState=changeState;

    }
}
```

желательно живой пример с пояснениями так как начал изучать тестирование тоже